# Como faço para executar uma ação de cálculo de valor de revenda de um produto no próprio código PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Minha tabela `produto` existe a coluna `valor_revenda` que simplesmente pega o valor da coluna
`valor_compra` da mesma tabela e **realiza o cálculo de revenda de 50% encima do valor do produto**.

- Ex: `valor_revenda` = (`valor_compra` + (`valor_compra` * 0.50))

Me recomendaram **deixar de lado o uso de triggers e fazer operações diretamente em código PHP**.

No meu código que faz o INSERT de um produto **deve possui esse tipo de cálculo direto no código PHP**, mais eu sou iniciante em PHP e **não sei como fazer essas operações diretamente no PHP**, alguém poderia me auxiliar?

### Tabela `produto`

```
CREATE TABLE produto (
  cd_produto INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(30),
  marca VARCHAR(30),
  codigo_barra VARCHAR(15),
  cor VARCHAR(30),
  tamanho VARCHAR(2),
  CHECK (tamanho IN ('P','M','G','GG')),
  genero CHAR(1),
  CHECK (genero IN ('M','F')),
  quantidade INT,
  valor_compra DECIMAL(7,2), 
  valor_revenda DECIMAL(7,2)
);
```

- Código de inserção no PHP

```
<?php
        require_once 'conexao.php'; 

        if(isset($_POST['Inserir'])){
 
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $marca = $_POST['marca'];
            $codigo_barra = $_POST['codigo_barra'];
            $cor = $_POST['cor'];
            $tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
            $genero = $_POST['genero'];
            $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
            $valor_compra = $_POST['valor_compra'];

            try {

                $insercao = "INSERT INTO produto (nome,marca,codigo_barra,cor,tamanho,genero,quantidade,valor_compra) 
                VALUES (:nome,:marca,:codigo_barra,:cor,:tamanho,:genero,:quantidade,:valor_compra)";

                $insere_dados = $conexao->prepare($insercao);

                $insere_dados->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':marca',$marca);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':codigo_barra',$codigo_barra);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':cor',$cor);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':tamanho',$tamanho);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':genero',$genero);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_compra',$valor_compra);

                $insere_dados->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $falha_insercao) {
                echo "A inserção não foi feita".$falha_insercao->getMessage();
            }
        }           
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, não sei se é tão básico a esse nível o que você quer, mas darei uma colher de chá por ser iniciante em PHP. Pelo que entendi, antes do seu try, insira:

```
$valor_revenda = ($valor_compra + ($valor_compra * 0.50))
```

Após isso, altere sua inserção no banco de dados, adicionando o campo valor_revenda que já está presente na tabela, segundo informado, dessa forma:

```
 try {

            $insercao = "INSERT INTO produto (nome,marca,codigo_barra,cor,tamanho,genero,quantidade,valor_compra,valor_revenda) 
            VALUES (:nome,:marca,:codigo_barra,:cor,:tamanho,:genero,:quantidade,:valor_compra,:valor_revenda)";

            $insere_dados = $conexao->prepare($insercao);

            $insere_dados->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':marca',$marca);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':codigo_barra',$codigo_barra);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':cor',$cor);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':tamanho',$tamanho);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':genero',$genero);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_compra',$valor_compra);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_revenda',$valor_revenda);

            $insere_dados->execute();

        }
```

Comment: por que devo inserir ```$valor_revenda = ($valor_compra + ($valor_compra * 0.50));``` antes do ```try```?

Comment: Na verdade, ```valor_revenda``` não é adicionado mesmo, nem no código de INSERT ou UPDATE.

Comment: Teria algum problema se eu não adicionasse ```valor_revenda```?

Comment: O valor_revenda é a variável que irá salvar o seu novo valor de revenda. Após isso, você passará essa variável para o banco de dados.

Comment: Precisa colocar ```$valor_revenda = $_POST['valor_revenda'];``` e ```$valor_revenda = ($valor_compra + ($valor_compra * 0.50))``` ou só apenas ```$valor_revenda = ($valor_compra + ($valor_compra * 0.50))``` fora do ```try```?

Comment: Utilize o código da exata forma que eu disse. Nada mais nada menos.

Comment: Obrigado Marcos, deu certo.